# Prolog returning only the max value from all iterations

Tags: prolog

I have a method that returns me a number on all `iterations`, but now I need to returns only the max value from all of the `iterations` that were done.

```
find_max(X, Y):-
    find_number(X, Y).
```

So the `find_number()` returns only 1 number and some text alongside it. So for example if I were to ran it I would get this output:

```
X = 1, Y = me;
X = 5, Y = you;
X = 6, Y = he;
```

And the only output I need to return is the `X = 6, Y = he;`. 
I am using `SWI-Prolog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more portable alternative to the `library(aggregate)` posted by Willem, as the library is only available in a few Prolog systems, is:

```
find_max_alt(Xm, Ym) :-
    setof(max(X, Y), find_number(X, Y), Solutions),
    reverse(Solutions, [max(Xm, Ym)| _]).
```

This solution also appears to required a smaller number of inferences. Using the data in the question, we get:

```
?- time(find_max(Xm, Ym)).
% 40 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (83% CPU, 800000 Lips)
Xm = 6,
Ym = he.
```

Versus:

```
?- time(find_max_alt(Xm, Ym)).
% 25 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (76% CPU, 675676 Lips)
Xm = 6,
Ym = he.
```

The `setof/3` predicate is a standard predicate. The `reverse/2` predicate is a common list predicate (and much simpler to define than the predicates in the `aggregate` library.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with 3 variables? So lets say I have find_number(Number, Name, List) and I need only the one with the highest number.

Comment: No problem there. The `setof/3` predicate sorts the solutions using *standard order*. In this case, it means that the solutions will be sorted first by `Number`, than by `Name`, and finally by `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`aggregate`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) library for that:

```
:- use_module(library(aggregate)).

find_max(Xm, Ym):-
    aggregate(max(X, Y), find_number(X, Y), max(Xm, Ym)).
```

Comment: Is the first variable in max() always the number or it does not matter?

Comment: @kataroty: it matters in the sense that `max` first looks to the first element, then to the second as tie breaker, and so on.